# HTML Email : td with triangle to the left side

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

Rather than having separate `td` for triangle , I would like to make the content `td` with **left arrow** triangle. Just like in the image.

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td width="2%" align="center" valign="middle" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 10px;">
      <p style="width: 0;height: 0;border-style: solid;border-width: 5px 10px 5px 0;border-color: transparent #fa4b00 transparent transparent; vertical-align: middle"></p>
    </td>

    <td width="78%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">

      <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; padding-left: 10px;">11 -20 : 11:40 </span>
      <br>
      <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:12px; padding-left: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;"> Tea Break </span>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Here is the image]

Any Help Would be Grateful.

Comment: These are normally achieved using `:before` or `:after` pseudo-selectors; neither of which can be declared inline.  You can do this via a `<style>` tag embedded in your HTML, but run the risk of that being stripped by services like G-Mail, etc.

Comment: exactly.. and i can't use `<style>` , as some email clients don't render such stuffs. I have checked in Gmail , but didn't work.. :(

Comment: I've come across this before and had to resort to using a table column for a transparent image with the triangle in, and then a column for the data to the right. I know it's not ideal but I think at the moment it's the only way you'll be able to achieve this

Comment: mark the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this is for [html-email](/questions/tagged/html-email), I would advise you to use an `img`, to support all the email clients

```html
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>

    <td width="2%" align="right" valign="middle" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 10px;">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRTb.png" style="vertical-align:top;" />
    </td>

    <td width="78%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">

      <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; padding-left: 10px;">11 -20 : 11:40 </span>
      <br>
      <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:12px; padding-left: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;"> Tea Break </span>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The solution for using CSS triangles using `border` won't work (as expected) in Outlook 2007-2013, so,if you are going with that, you might need to take a look at this [article](http://emailcodegeek.com/css-triangles/)

Where you have to define the triangle's shape with VML and call it defining its color and size.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by using this kind of workflow then work with margins.

In this example i gave

```
margin-right:-3px;
```

but i would suggest using pseudo elements before and after.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    
     <td width="2%" align="center" valign="middle" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <p style="width: 0;height: 0;border-style: solid;border-width: 5px 10px 5px 0;border-color: transparent #fa4b00 transparent transparent; vertical-align: middle;"></p>
                                </td>

                                <td width="78%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">

                                    <span  style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; padding-left: 10px;">11 -20 : 11:40 </span><br>
                                    <span  style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:12px; padding-left: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;"> Tea Break </span>

                                </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: yes @dippas i just checked and that is  correct. to make it work in every browser the margin:-3px; can be remove and the table tag can be changed to this <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

Comment: I'm referring to making a triangle using `border`, look at my answer

Comment: you answer doesn't work in outlook either because you are using just an image instead of the span and you are using margin which is unsupported in outlook. This updated answers is the solution

Comment: `margin` only doesn't work in outlook.com, which is different from outlook 2007-2013, and as I mentioned

Comment: @leli.1337... in your code , if i do **select all** , then that triangle doesn't select ..